# Ambiguous exception when using webflux bean validation (WebExchangeBindException vs ConstraintViolationException)

Tags: java, spring-webflux, bean-validation

I am using Webflux and will proceed with field verification using bean validation.

Trying to respond to field errors using `@RestControllerAdvice`

When specifying a group in the bean validation field
Can I know the reason why the `Exception` type is different?

An exception to `WebExchangeBindException` occurs when no group is specified.

When you specify a group, an exception to `ConstraintViolationException` occurs.

I want a unified exception and to know if `@RestControllerAdvice` should manage the exception separately.

I looked it up for a second.
I don't think `AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver` uses groups to validate fields...

I wanted a unified exception, `WebExchangeBindException` or `ConstraintViolationException`

- `spring-boot` - 2.5.3
- `spring-boot-starter-validation - 2.5.3
- `spring-boot-starter-webflux` - 5.3.9

---

**stack trace**

- When the length is exceeded.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "12345678901",
  "age": 30,
  "address" : "test",
  "phoneNumber": "010-1234-5678"
}
```

```
org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebExchangeBindException: Validation failed for argument at index 0 in method: public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<com.example.practicejavaannotation.entity.User> com.example.practicejavaannotation.controller.UserController.create(com.example.practicejavaannotation.dto.request.UserDto), with 1 error(s): [Field error in object 'userDto' on field 'name': rejected value [12345678901]; codes [Length.userDto.name,Length.name,Length.java.lang.String,Length]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [userDto.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name],10,1]; default message [길이가 1에서 10 사이여야 합니다]] 
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.validate(AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.java:257) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.lambda$readBody$5(AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.java:196) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:185) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:547) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:252) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

- When the name field is missing

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "age": 30,
  "address" : "test",
  "phoneNumber": "010-1234-5678"
}
```

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: create.userDto.name: 공백일 수 없습니다
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at com.example.practicejavaannotation.controller.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$37579d7.create(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:336) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:101) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:547) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:252) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

---

Marker interface for separating groups

This is the class used to create or update

Field cannot be null at creation time.

Some of the fields could be null when updated.

```
package com.example.practicejavaannotation.dto.request;

import javax.validation.groups.Default;

public interface OnCreate extends Default {
}
```

```
package com.example.practicejavaannotation.dto.request;

import javax.validation.groups.Default;

public interface OnUpdate extends Default {
}
```

---

- UserDto

```
package com.example.practicejavaannotation.dto.request;

import com.example.practicejavaannotation.entity.User;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import java.time.Instant;

@Getter
public class UserDto extends BaseDto<User> {

    @NotBlank(groups = OnCreate.class)
    @Length(min = 1, max = 10)
    private final String name;

    @NotNull(groups = OnCreate.class)
    @Min(1)
    @Max(100)
    private final Integer age;

    @NotBlank(groups = OnCreate.class)
    @Length(max = 255)
    private final String address;

    @NotBlank(groups = OnCreate.class)
    @Pattern(regexp = "[\\d]{3}-[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{4}")
    private final String phoneNumber;

    public UserDto(String name, Integer age, String address, String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public User create() {
        return new User(name, age, address, phoneNumber, Instant.now().getEpochSecond());
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
        if (name != null) user.setName(name);
        if (age != null) user.setAge(age);
        if (address != null) user.setAddress(address);
        if (phoneNumber != null) user.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserDto{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", phoneNumber='" + phoneNumber + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

---

- UserController

```
package com.example.practicejavaannotation.controller;

import com.example.practicejavaannotation.dto.request.OnCreate;
import com.example.practicejavaannotation.dto.request.OnUpdate;
import com.example.practicejavaannotation.dto.request.UserDto;
import com.example.practicejavaannotation.entity.User;
import com.example.practicejavaannotation.service.UserService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Validated
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/user")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    public Mono<User> get(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> userService.read(userId));
    }

    @Validated(OnCreate.class)
    @PostMapping
    public Mono<User> create(@Valid  @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> userService.create(userDto));
    }

    @Validated(OnUpdate.class)
    @PatchMapping("/{userId}")
    public Mono<User> update(@PathVariable Long userId, @Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> userService.update(userId, userDto));
    }


}
```

---

- RestControllerAdvice

```
package com.example.practicejavaannotation.controller;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebExchangeBindException;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

@Slf4j
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalErrorController {

    @ExceptionHandler(WebExchangeBindException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(WebExchangeBindException e) {
        log.info("WebExchangeBindException : {}", e);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .body(Void.class);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        log.info("ConstraintViolationException : {}", e);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .body(Void.class);
    }

}
```

- EDIT
  stacktrace when group is removed in name field.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "age": 30,
  "address" : "test",
  "phoneNumber": "010-1234-5678"
}
```

```
org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebExchangeBindException: Validation failed for argument at index 0 in method: public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<com.example.practicejavaannotation.entity.User> com.example.practicejavaannotation.controller.UserController.create(com.example.practicejavaannotation.dto.request.UserDto), with 1 error(s): [Field error in object 'userDto' on field 'name': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.userDto.name,NotBlank.name,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [userDto.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name]]; default message [공백일 수 없습니다]] 
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.validate(AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.java:257) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.lambda$readBody$5(AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.java:196) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:185) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:547) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:252) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue.

Use `@Validated` when validating group field

I found this post.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-valid-vs-validated

> In Spring, we use JSR-303's @Valid annotation for method level validation. Moreover, we also use it to mark a member attribute for validation. However, this annotation doesn't support group validation.
> Groups help to limit the constraints applied during validation. One particular use case is UI wizards. Here, in the first step, we may have a certain sub-group of fields. In the subsequent step, there may be another group belonging to the same bean. Hence we need to apply constraints on these limited fields in each step, but @Valid doesn't support this.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
@Size(min = 1, max = 10)
```

or

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^\\w{1,10}$")
```

instead of

```
@Length(min = 1, max = 10)
```

Comment: If the name field does not exist when creating a user (cause `@NotBlank`) even with `@Size`, ConstraintViolationException will occur.


My question is why Exception is different if `@NotBlank` includes groups or not.


`@NotBlank(groups = OnCreate.class)` - ConstraintViolationException


`@NotBlank` - WebExchangeBindException